# How to display the error message (from the response of server) on the right or below the username inputt field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I implement authorization and registration in the application using Fomik and Yup.

But if I register the user which have `username`was already registered on my server, my local server gives me message error. And that's right. I need it.

**Where and when I'm getting an error message:**
After I wrote in all input fields(*including a username who is already registered*)and I press button submit then I click in my browser `Ctrl + shift + I` then the tab `Network`, then I click file request and tabs `Response` and there I see this:

`[{"message":"User with this username already exists","field":"username","validation":"unique"}]`

screenshot of image hosting:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/24c98548e2e83f9592c62560e7f3ab2d/1586694052/96796/1372209/ddd.png

**Then what do I need:**
I need that message error:
`User with this username already exists`
displayed to the right of or below the username input field.

What to add to the files myForm.js or in SignInput.js to display the error message(*Network tabs on browser/Response*) on the right or below the username input field?

some part of myForm.js:

```
const myForm = () => {
 const history = useHistory();

    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur} = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
          username: '',
          password: '',
         /............
      },
        validateOnBlur: false,
        validateOnchange: false,
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape({ 
          username: yup.string()      
           .required('This field is required'),
          password: yup.string()
           .required('This field is required')
           .min(6, 'This password is too short')
           .max(30, 'This passwors is too long'),
          /..........

      }),  

      onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          try {
              const res = await api('api/auth/register', {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
              });
              const token = res.token.token;
              localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);
              history.push("/home"); 
          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);   
          } 
      },  
    });

   return (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
       <SignupInput
         label="username"
         id="username" 
         inputProps={{
           name:'username',
           value: values.username,
           onChange: handleChange,
           onBlur: handleBlur,
       }}
       error={errors.username}
       />
     <SignupInput
         label="password"
         id="password" 
         inputProps={{
           name:'password',
           value: values.password,
           onChange: handleChange,
           onBlur: handleBlur,
           type:'password'
       }}
       error={errors.password}
       />
        /.............
       <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>
   </form>
   );
};
```

Also I write file SignupInput.js(where SignupInput component):

```
const SignupInput = ({
    label, inputProps, error, id,     
}) => (
        <div className="ffinput">
          <label htmlFor={id} className="ffinput-label">  
            {label}
          </label>
        <input {...inputProps} id={id} />    
          {error && <span className="ffinput-error">{error}</span>} 
        </div>
    );


SignupInput.propTypes = {                   
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,  
    inputProps: PropTypes.instanceOf(Object).isRequired,  
    error: PropTypes.string,
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired, 
};

SignupInput.defaultProps = { 
    error: '',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that validation error in catch block where you did `console.error(e)`. See what object it returns by consoling `e` which is your error object and then store it in state by selecting appropriate property from that error object/message and pass that state to your input prop.

Now since you are already passing that formik error in the **SignupInput** component, you now have to pass that error logically with along with formik errors. Like `errors={errors.password || backendErrorState}`. Or alternative way is to show it somewhere else like on the top in a separate div/component.

Comment: Can you show me the console.error(e), so that I could see what it is actually returning from the API call in the catch block.

Comment: You can get that error message like this
`const [validationErros, setValidationErros] = useState([]);
onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
  catch(e) {
              setValidationErros(e);
          } 
      },  
    });
`
Need to know structure of error first